# use SSH tunnel to baypass Captive portal

Tags: ssh, ssh-tunneling

I know that DNS tunneling is the good choice when we try to bypass captive portal, but i tried to do SSH tunneling instead of DNS but it doesn't works, technically speaking is that possible -bypass captive portal using SSH tunnel- ?

Comment: no one to answer ?

Answer (score 1):

While not authorized, you have no access (filter, redirection) from your computer to the internet. And while not authorized you have no access from any computer in the internet to your computer. Thus it is not possible to create a ssh tunnel, because you need at least one direction open.

Even if you have authorized and established an ssh connection (and maybe a tunnel), the connection will break, as soon as you unauthorize, because then your packets again get filtered or DNS or HTTP redirected.

There maybe other solutions to bypass a [captive portal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Captive_portal), but ssh can’t help you.